# Why is the view not changing? Xcode/Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have this code that checks if the user is logged into FB and if they are it changes the view

```
 if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil){
            print("Not Logged In")
        } else {
            print("Logged In")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNew", sender: nil)
        }
```

I've given labelled the Identifier correctly but it still doesnt change view it just continues as if the code wasn't there

The error:

```
2015-11-11 13:51:03.377 quiz[37727:1264770] Warning: Attempt to present <quiz.homeScreen: 0x7fb1bbc34910> on <quiz.ViewController: 0x7fb1bbe9af20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: Are you trying to perform this action in a callback/completion block?

Comment: where is this piece of code located? (viewController? and if yes where does the segue start from and where does it "segue" to)

Comment: `print("Logged In")` works?

Comment: This is in my viewDidLoad() method because I don't want it to display the login page otherwise. It is from my ViewController.swift to my homePage.swift

Comment: @zcui93 yeah it works

Comment: Did you get any comments in the log as to why the performSegue is failing?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon added the log in question now

Comment: Well, there you go, the log gave you the answer that @Joseph Lord mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling it from `viewDidLoad`. Until the view controller is presented I don't think that you can perform a segue from it.

Try moving the code to initiate the segue to `viewDidAppear` (not sure if it can work in `viewWillAppear` but you can try that too).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that there is a segue that connects the two scenes, with an identifier equal to "showNew"  My bet is that the segue is not actually connecting the scenes in the storyboard, or that the identifier is not set.

[image]